# How can I use nginx to set a vhost and webroot on a URI of an existing vhost?

Tags: nginx, dns, webserver

I want to send a vhost's requests to `git.domain1.tld` to `sub.domain2.tld/git`

I suppose that would conflict with overwritten files so how can I get that domain to point to that location?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass https://sub.domain2.tld/git;
  }
```

Or

```
rewrite ^/$ https://sub.domain2.tld/git permanent;
rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://sub.domain2.tld/git/$1 permanent;
```